# Specify default format for Decimal.ToString() method

Tags: .net, formatting, decimal, tostring

I have an application with a lot of calls to [Decimal.ToString(void)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0b22a4x2). The default format is not what is needed. I could change these calls to one of the other [Decimal.ToString overloads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Decimal.ToString), but it would be nicer if I didn't have to. So, is there a way to specify a different format for the Decimal.ToString(void) method so that I don't have to modify any of the calls to this method?

**Update**

As the answer below indicates, it is possible to do what I want, but I should not do so as it is not good programming practice. There are many alternative approaches which involve rewriting the calls; the approach I plan to go with is to store the desired format as a string constant and pass that to the calls:

```
class Example
{
    const string s_DecimalFormat = "N2";

    private decimal myDecimal1 = 12.345;
    private decimal myDecimal2 = 6.7;

    public void Method()
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine(myDecimal1.ToString(s_DecimalFormat));
        System.Console.WriteLine(myDecimal2.ToString(s_DecimalFormat));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theoretically, if you change [`System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture(v=vs.110).aspx) to something that formats a decimal the way you want, this would work. It will open up a *huge* can of worms you don't want to touch with a ten-foot pole. **Do not do this.** Change all your calls. Maybe write a method for it.

Comment: Would you be willing to explain why changing `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` would not be a good idea?

Comment: @DanStevens Mostly because it alters the whole program. Many methods use this internally if you don't pass another FormatProvider. And I guess the OP does not. Also, altering *just* the decimal format cannot be anticipated by fellow programmers. It's against the principle of least surprise. Changing it to another culture is one thing, changing a culture internally or making up your own is bad.

Answer (score 0):

A extension method might be nice here. Something like:

```
public static string ToMyString(this decimal value)
{
   return value.ToString("your formatting");
}
```

I agree with @nvoigt that changing the globalization settings is a bad idea

Comment: Not quite what I'm looking for; I was hoping to avoid rewriting any of the the calls to `ToString(void)` - this would involve replacing those calls with `ToMyString()`.

Answer (score 0):

You could write your own extension method.  As an example:

```
public class Test
{

    private void DoStuff()
    {

        Decimal d = new Decimal();
        d = 0.5M;

        Console.WriteLine("{0}", d);
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", d.ToCustomString());

    }

}

public static class Extensions
{
    public static string ToCustomString(this Decimal number)
    {
        return string.Format("Blah {0}", number.ToString());
    }
}
```

Output:

```
0.5
Blah 0.5
```

When using Decimal.ToCustomString instead of ToString, at least in this case, the decimals are prefaced with "Blah "

You can write the extension method in the format that you would like to return, granted you would need to use the extension method rather than .ToString()